# Empty test suite with karma in Intellij

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, intellij-idea, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm running angularjs unit testing using karma.
I have 2 ways to do that:

1. using grunt
2. using intellij (with the play icons on the left of the editor)

Until now everything worked fine, but now only grunt is really running the tests. Intellij gives me this output:

> Empty test suite.
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

I don't know if it's because I updated Intellij recently, or because I removed node_modules and reinstalled it..

this is my karma.conf.js file:

```
// Karma configuration
// http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html
// Generated on 2016-01-01 using
// generator-karma 1.0.1

module.exports = function (config) {
    'use strict';

    config.set({
        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: true,

        // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
        basePath: '../',

        // testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
        // as well as any additional frameworks (requirejs/chai/sinon/...)
        frameworks: [
            'jasmine-jquery',
            'jasmine'
        ],

        reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],


        preprocessors: {
            'app/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js'],
            'test/**/*.es6': ['babel'],
            'app/**/*.js': ['coverage']
        },

        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            // bower:js
            'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            'bower_components/ipaddr.js/lib/ipaddr.js',
            'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
            'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
            'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
            'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
            'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
            'bower_components/d3/d3.js',
            'bower_components/d3-cloud/build/d3.layout.cloud.js',
            'bower_components/d3-more-plugins/build/d3-plugins.js',
            'bower_components/nvd3/build/nv.d3.js',
            'bower_components/angular-nvd3/dist/angular-nvd3.js',
            'bower_components/velocity/velocity.js',
            'bower_components/velocity/velocity.ui.js',
            'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
            'bower_components/javascript-detect-element-resize/detect-element-resize.js',
            'bower_components/angular-gridster/src/angular-gridster.js',
            'bower_components/perfect-scrollbar/js/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.js',
            'bower_components/iso-3166-country-codes-angular/dist/iso-3166-country-codes-angular.min.js',
            'bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js',
            'bower_components/lodash/lodash.js',
            'bower_components/angular-vs-repeat/src/angular-vs-repeat.js',
            'bower_components/moment/moment.js',
            'bower_components/lumx/dist/lumx.js',
            'bower_components/v-accordion/dist/v-accordion.js',
            'bower_components/ua-parser-js/src/ua-parser.js',
            'bower_components/smooth-scrollbar/dist/smooth-scrollbar.js',
            'bower_components/angular-smooth-scrollbar/dist/angular-smooth-scrollbar.js',
            'bower_components/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js',
            'bower_components/codemirror/addon/fold/foldcode.js',
            'bower_components/codemirror/addon/fold/foldgutter.js',
            'bower_components/codemirror/addon/fold/xml-fold.js',
            'bower_components/codemirror/addon/fold/brace-fold.js',
            'bower_components/codemirror/addon/search/searchcursor.js',
            'bower_components/codemirror/addon/scroll/simplescrollbars.js',
            'bower_components/codemirror/addon/selection/active-line.js',
            'bower_components/codemirror/addon/edit/matchbrackets.js',
            'bower_components/codemirror/addon/mode/multiplex.js',
            'bower_components/codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js',
            'bower_components/codemirror/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js',
            'bower_components/codemirror/mode/css/css.js',
            'bower_components/codemirror/mode/http/http.js',
            'bower_components/codemirror/mode/xml/xml.js',
            'bower_components/angular-ui-codemirror/ui-codemirror.js',
            'bower_components/angular-resizable/src/angular-resizable.js',
            'bower_components/ngstorage/ngStorage.js',
            'bower_components/ng-csv/build/ng-csv.js',
            'bower_components/jquery-mousewheel/jquery.mousewheel.js',
            'bower_components/js-beautify/js/lib/beautify.js',
            'bower_components/js-beautify/js/lib/beautify-css.js',
            'bower_components/js-beautify/js/lib/beautify-html.js',
            'bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js',
            'bower_components/angular-ui-sortable/sortable.js',
            'bower_components/jqueryui-touch-punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js',
            'bower_components/lz-string/libs/lz-string.min.js',
            'bower_components/tippy.js/dist/tippy.js',
            'bower_components/crypto-js/core.js',
            'bower_components/crypto-js/enc-base64.js',
            'bower_components/crypto-js/md5.js',
            'bower_components/crypto-js/evpkdf.js',
            'bower_components/crypto-js/cipher-core.js',
            'bower_components/crypto-js/aes.js',
            'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js',
            'bower_components/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js',
            // endbower
            "app/scripts/**/*.js",
            "app/modules/some-folder/scripts/module.es6",
            "app/modules/mobile-replay/scripts/module.es6",
            "app/modules/web-replay/scripts/module.es6",
            "app/modules/period-picker/scripts/period-picker.es6",
            //"test/mock/**/*.es6",
            "app/modules/**/*.es6",
            "test/spec/**/*.es6",
            'app/views/**/*.html',
            'app/modules/*/views/**/*.html'
        ],

        proxies: {
            '/data/': '/data/'
        },

        // list of files / patterns to exclude
        exclude: [
            'app/modules/web-replay/scripts/replay-libs.js',
            'app/detector-beacon.min.js'
        ],

        // web server port
        port: 8082,

        // Start these browsers, currently available:
        // - Chrome
        // - ChromeCanary
        // - Firefox
        // - Opera
        // - Safari (only Mac)
        // - PhantomJS
        // - IE (only Windows)
        browsers: [
            'ChromeHeadless'
        ],

        // Which plugins to enable
        plugins: [
            '@metahub/karma-jasmine-jquery',
            'karma-*'
        ],

        ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
            stripPrefix: 'app/',
            moduleName: 'html-templates'
        },

        babelPreprocessor: {
            options: {
                presets: [['env',{
                    "targets": {
                        "browsers": ["last 10 Chrome major versions", "last 10 Firefox major versions", "ie >= 11", "safari >= 9"]
                    }
                }]],
                sourceMap: 'inline'
            }
        },

        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
        singleRun: false,

        colors: true,

        // level of logging
        // possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

        browserDisconnectTolerance: 8,
        browserNoActivityTimeout: 10000,

        // Uncomment the following lines if you are using grunt's server to run the tests
        // proxies: {
        //   '/': 'http://localhost:9000/'
        // },
        // URL root prevent conflicts with the site root
        // urlRoot: '_karma_'
    });
};
```

Example Project (I Can't upload my project):

Tested file

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('PasswordController', function PasswordController($scope) {
  $scope.password = '';
  $scope.grade = function() {
    var size = $scope.password.length;
    if (size > 8) {
      $scope.strength = 'strong';
    } else if (size > 3) {
      $scope.strength = 'medium';
    } else {
      $scope.strength = 'weak';
    }
  };
});
```

testing file:

```
describe('PasswordController', function() {
  beforeEach(module('app'));

  var $controller, $rootScope;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_){
    // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
    $controller = _$controller_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  }));

  describe('$scope.grade', function() {
    it('sets the strength to "strong" if the password length is >8 chars', function() {
      var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
      var controller = $controller('PasswordController', { $scope: $scope });
      $scope.password = 'longerthaneightchars';
      $scope.grade();
      expect($scope.strength).toEqual('strong');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: configuration looks correct at first sight... Does running `node path/to/karma/bin/karma start  karma.conf.js` work in terminal? sample project that shows up the issue would be helpful

Comment: Hi, when I'm running karma from console like you wrote, it works fine... only the intellij gives me the emty test suite...

Comment: it's strange; please share a sample project I can use to recreate the issue

Comment: I Added a sample 'project' from angularjs site, I tried to run karma.conf.js with intellij and it runs all tests fine, bu when I try to run a specific test (like a 'describe' section or 'it' section) it's not working

Comment: works fine for me using these files - test passes as usual when I run a single test/suite... I'll attach my test project to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34243, please check if you can recreate the issue with it

Comment: lena, The karma you used is much more updated than my karma (0.13), I updated my karma and it's working now, looks like intellij no longer supports this version of karma...

Comment: I see, thanks for update:)